# How to set Default Parameter or Optional Parameter in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

```
public void ZIPFiles(String SourceFilePath, string SourceFileName, int NoOfItemstoZip, string SourceFileExtension, string FileSizeLimit, string CategoryofSorting, string DestinationFilePath, String DestinationFileName, string DropBoxPath, string DropBoxFileName)
{
}
```

In here i declare Function with many parameter.But when i call the function i use only 4 parameter. Like

```
ZIPFiles(SourceFilePath, SourceFileName, DestinationFilePath, DestinationFileName);
```

But it showing me errors. I do not want to delete my code which is in function declaration. I can pass null values for remaining arguments but i need any other way to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional parameters, so in that case your method declaration should be like this :

```
    public void ZIPFiles(String SourceFilePath, string SourceFileName, string DestinationFilePath, String DestinationFileName, int NoOfItemstoZip = 0, string SourceFileExtension = "", string FileSizeLimit ="", string CategoryofSorting = "", string DropBoxPath = "", string DropBoxFileName = "")
    {
    }
```

You can set any default value for this optional parameters, I've just set it as " " (empty string) and '0' in case of string and integers. Then you can call it as you've called this method. But make sure all your required parameters must be at left side and all optional parameters should be appears in last (right side) in order.

Also, you can try 'params' when you know that other parameter may be of same type, like this;

```
    public void ZIPFiles(String SourceFilePath, string SourceFileName, string DestinationFilePath, String DestinationFileName, int NoOfItemstoZip = 0, params string[] allParameters)
    {
    }
```

Here I've set 'params' as array of 'String' parameters.

Comment: Also, you can't use String.Empty as a default parameter, since it should be a compile time constant.

Comment: ya.but it is an generic , so if i pass some other argument like  i add CategoryofSorting  and i do not want to pass DestinationFileName means what i want to do?

Comment: In that case you also need to declare DestinationFileName as optional parameter. So the main idea is that all the parameters which you feel that it may be passed or not, need to be declare as optional. Then whatever you will not pass the default value will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can define a function with [optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx),

> An optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition.
>   If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used.

A default value must be one of the following types of expressions: 
 like the following:

1. A constant expression;
2. An expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such
3. As an enum or a struct;

an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

```
public void ZIPFiles(String SourceFilePath,
                             string SourceFileName, string DestinationFilePath,
                             String DestinationFileName,
                             string SourceFileExtension=".txt", string FileSizeLimit="2mb",
                             string CategoryofSorting="", string DropBoxPath="default",
                             int NoOfItemstoZip=0, string DropBoxFileName="default")
        {
            //Do your operations here
        }
```

Now you can call the method like this :

```
  ZIPFiles(SourceFilePath, SourceFileName, DestinationFilePath, DestinationFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

make int NoOfItemstoZip=0, and string parametername=null

that's the way to define optional parameter in c# so now if you pass any value it will take that one otherwise it will assign null

Comment: `null`  will lead to exception use `string.Empty` or simply `""`

Comment: it's depends but if you want use so use string.empty not "" because "" always create new object

Answer (score 0):

[un-lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5195227/un-lucky)'s answer is correct, however try not to have so many parameters on a method, if you think a method does require these many parameters, create an object to hold these values and then pass this object to your method. This way you can have better control over what defaults you want to set.